# Using hexagonal image as button

Tags: python, image, button, python-3.6, hexagonal-tiles

I have a problem: I want to make a honeycomb shape in which every hexagon is a clickable button, but don't know how.

I tried to make it by Button() and window() from Tkinter, but its shape is rectangluar. I need its shape to be hexagonal.

EDIT:
I added a picture, just want each of these hexagons to be separate clickable button. Is it doable?

I could add that I am learning programming on my own and I don't know much, but I searched a lot and one and only thing that I found was creating rectangular button. :/

[Honeycomb pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaSMd.png)

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stackoverflow! I recommend you take the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)
to know your way arround here (and earn your first badge also ;) ). Also to improve the chances of getting useful answers
please check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and also how to create [Complete, Minimal, and Verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Well ,there is no direct method in tkinter to create shaped buttons other than the usual rectangle one, but you can do it by playing with colors and images.

- Crop an image in the shape and color, in which you wish your button to be.
- Then use the Button widget, to create the button having that particular image

**For example:**

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
image_button = PhotoImage(root, file="hexagonal_button.png")
button_hex = Button(root, bg='white',border='0', image=image_button)
button_hex.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

- Or else, you may try other GUI toolkits such as:
- **wxPython**
- **PyQt**
- **Kivy** and many more ...